# How to pass the build hash as an environment variable in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, environment-variables

I've got an internal application that's built using webpack that gets deployed frequently. In order to make bug reporting easier, I want to include an environment variable of the build hash `[hash]` that webpack adds to bundle names. This would let me quickly determine if the user is on the latest release.

Using the `DefinePlugin`, the following does not interpolate the string and instead just stores a literal `[hash]` string.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    'HASH': JSON.stringify('[hash]')
  }
})
```

Is there any way to access the hash directly as a variable or is there a specific way to make it interpolate?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#extendedapiplugin

> ExtendedAPIPlugin
>
> `new webpack.ExtendedAPIPlugin()`
>
> Adds useful free vars to the bundle.
>
> `__webpack_hash__` The hash of the compilation available as free var.

This can't be used in the `DefinePlugin()` but it creates a global `__webpack_hash__` variable that can be accessed from anywhere inside your bundle.

```
var hash = __webpack_hash__;
```

Comment: Does this mean `__webpack_hash__` is just a global var in my bundle now? or is there some other way to access it?

Comment: Yes, it is. I don't know another ways to use it.

Comment: It may be worth noting that if you use interpolation in html files "${__webpack_hash__}", the hash won't be the correct one. So I'm falling back to setting the hash in the html at runtime.

Comment: You're missing the underscores in the var name.