# Alert users to refresh when there is a new deployment in react using web-pack and not create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am trying to alert users when there is a new version deployed in my react app. Here I am using webpack to bundle our modular application which yields a deployable /dist directory. Once the contents of /dist have been deployed to a server, clients (typically browsers) will hit that server to grab the site and its assets. I am using caching techniques as mentioned in https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/ and for each deployment, I am getting new content hash id.

I need something similar to the below screenshot where the user gets a notification to refresh the page. Is there any way you guys can help me out in this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Here are a whole bunch of ways to get the version/hash id into your app: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50228128/how-to-inject-webpack-build-hash-to-application-code.