# Next.js PWA Error: Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps, manifest, workbox

I am trying to create a `Next.js PWA` with `WebpackPwaManifest` and `NextWorkboxPlugin`.

Whenever I start the app the `service worker` is registered but it can't find the `manifest.json`.

Here is my `next.config.js` file, it contains how I generate `manifest` and `serviceworker` on each build:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path');
const NextWorkboxPlugin = require('next-workbox-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackPwaManifest = require('webpack-pwa-manifest');

const { parsed: keys } = require('dotenv').config({
    path: './keys.env'
})

module.exports = {
    webpack(config, { isServer, buildId, dev }) {

         ...
       
        const workboxOptions = {
            clientsClaim: true,
            skipWaiting: true,
            globPatterns: [path.resolve('.next/static/*'), path.resolve('.next/static/commons/*')],
            modifyUrlPrefix: {
                '.next': '_next',
            },
            runtimeCaching: [
                {
                    urlPattern: '/',
                    handler: 'networkFirst',
                    options: {
                        cacheName: 'html-cache',
                    },
                },
                
                ...
            ],
        };

        config.plugins.push(
            new NextWorkboxPlugin({
                buildId,
                ...workboxOptions,
            }),

            new WebpackPwaManifest({
                name: 'appname',
                short_name: 'shortname',
                description: 'desc',
                background_color: '#ffffff',
                crossorigin: 'use-credentials',
                inject: true,
                start_url: "/",
                icons: [
                    {
                        src: path.resolve('./public/images/Iconlogo.svg'),
                        sizes: [96, 128, 192, 256, 384, 512],
                    },
                    {
                        src: path.resolve('./public/images/Iconlogo.svg'),
                        size: '1024x1024'
                    },
                    {
                        src: path.resolve('./public/images/Iconlogo.svg'),
                        size: '1024x1024',
                        purpose: 'maskable'
                    }
                ]
            }));
        return config
    },
  ...
}
```

So this is working as expected... generated the SW and the manifest as well.
[image: Manifest and SW Generation]

But when I run the app, I get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/manifest.json 404 (Not Found)
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

I am including manifest in _document.tsx, using next.js `Head` tags:

```
export default class MyDocument extends Document {
    render() {
        return (
            <Html lang="en">
                <Head>
                    <link rel="manifest" crossOrigin="use-credentials" href="/manifest.json" />
                </Head>
                < body >
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        )
    }
}
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't generate a `manifest.json`, you generate `manifest.<hash>.json`. It'll 404 as you're not passing the correct asset URL. You need to pass the hash into the `href` attribute.

Comment: @rschristian But the hash is changing accordingly to the build... any suggestion on how can I sync hash in ```<head>``` to ```webpack buildId```? I already tried to pass the ```buildId``` as ```static string``` and did not work. Unfortunately, the ```hash``` is required, so I cant generate without the ```hash```.

Comment: Managed to disable ```hash``` in file names by passing ```fingerprints: false``` into ```WebpackPwaManifest```. But unfortunately still can't find the file.

Comment: I moved ```manifest.json``` and generated ```icons``` into ```public```... Might not be the best solution as manifest is generated on the build, but it should not change content anyway.

Comment: This is how you handle Webpack hashes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50228128/how-to-inject-webpack-build-hash-to-application-code