# Using Webpack 4 can access the hash or contenthash in my javascript code, not the html?

Tags: webpack

How can I access the [name] and [contenthash] within the my code itself.

I want my loader.js file to reference the other script's file name.

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js',
    loader: './src/loader.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the ExtendedAPIPlugin

```
new webpack.ExtendedAPIPlugin()
```

`__webpack_hash__` being a global, you can access everywhere.

Comment: When used in my bundled script it says: ReferenceError: __webpack_hash__ is not defined

Comment: Found this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082976/how-to-pass-the-build-hash-as-an-environment-variable-in-webpack

Comment: We just need to add this  plugin   new webpack.ExtendedAPIPlugin()
to get use of that global varaible __webpack_hash__